# NodeJS: How to use Promise.all in order to execute a method once multiple requests are executed?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise, nodejs-server, promise.all

I am having a `NodeJS` project, where I have array of N parameters and I need to call an endpoint N times (once with each parameter). Then I need to listen once all the responses are returned and to execute a certain function only once all the results are retrieved.

I know how to implement the above in front-end frameworks, where I am using axios and then I am storing the responses from the axios in an array (for example `responsePromises`) and then I am executing

```
return Promise.all(responsePromises).then(responses => { {
    //do something with the responses[0], responses[1], etc...
}
```

So the above is something that I already use successfully. The issue is, now I need to do the same in my back-end (which I mentioned is a `NodeJS` project).

Below is given the code that I am using for retrieving the data from a single endpoint and on success, I am executing the `successMethod`.

```
let paramArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
let parsedURL = url.parse("https://this-is-my-url.com?param=" + paramArray[0]);
let proto = reqUrl.indexOf('https://') === 0 ? https : http;

let request = proto.get({ 
    hostname: parsedURL.hostname,
    port: parsedURL.port,
    path: parsedURL.path
}, (response) => {
    //do something on success
    successMethod(); 
})
request.on('error', (e) => {
    //do something on error
    errorMethod(); 
});
request.end();
```

What I am not sure is, how to apply the implementation with `Promise.all` inside of the `NodeJS` code which I am using? Would be ideal if I can somehow loop through the `paramArray` array again, to store the promises into another `responsePromises` array and to execute my successMethod only when I have all the responses returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution to my problem:

```
let responsePromises = [];
paramArray.forEach(i=>{
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let parsedURL = url.parse("https://this-is-my-url.com?param=" + i);
    let proto = reqUrl.indexOf('https://') === 0 ? https : http;
  
    const request =  proto.get({ 
      hostname: parsedURL.hostname,
      port: parsedURL.port,
      path: parsedURL.path
    }, (response) => {
      resolve(response);
    })
  
    request.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e);
    });

    request.end();
  });
  responsePromises.push(myPromise);
})

Promise.all(responsePromises).then(responses => {
   responses.forEach(response => {
     successMethod();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) Promise all, that makes sure all promises have returned.

```
proto.get({ 
    hostname: parsedURL.hostname,
    port: parsedURL.port,
    path: parsedURL.path
}, async(response) => {
    //make responsePromises array
    
    const res = await Promise.all(responsePromises);

    //do something on success
    successMethod(); 
})
```

EDIT after comment:

```
const responsePromises = paramArray.map(i=>{
  let parsedURL = url.parse("https://this-is-my-url.com?param=" + i);
  let proto = reqUrl.indexOf('https://') === 0 ? https : http;
  
  const request =  proto.get({ 
    hostname: parsedURL.hostname,
    port: parsedURL.port,
    path: parsedURL.path
  });
  
  request.on('error', (e) => {
    //do something on error
    errorMethod(); 
  });
  
  return request;
})

Promise.all(responsePromises).then(responses => {
   successMethod();  
})
```

Comment: and how should I assign promises into the `responsePromises` array? That's what is not clear for me in NodeJS?

Comment: Have updated answer i guess you want to process paramArray and then promise all them.

Comment: The result still does not match with my needs. In the `successMethod`I am processing the responses from `responses` array one by one (as I would normally do if this was a single request) and the processing is failing. **I extracted the keys from the response objects** in both cases (**when using it as a single request v.s. when using it as a part of array of promises**). The same request has different keys (in it's response object) for both cases. Please check it [here](https://prnt.sc/11vdvr5)